# How do I get my Gitlab CE installation to detect git repos in custom git_data_dirs directory

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I have a local installation of Gitlab CE on a Vagrant box (installed there as a means of demoing to the dev team and shot-callers) and I've configured the `git_data_dirs` setting as follows:

```
git_data_dirs({"default" => "/var/git"})
```

Inside this directory, there is another called `repositories`, which I can only assume Gitlab has added when I ran `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.

Within this `repositories/` directory, I have managed to `git clone --mirror <git-repo>` which gives me the `*.git` I need.

How do I get Gitlab to detect this as a project, or how do I get Gitlab to add a new project using this?

Comment: If I get you question correctly, you try import git repos into your installation. If so, what prevents you from using the built-in import capabilities?

Comment: From what I'm able to deduce, I think it's SSH constraints or file permissions which I don't want to change as the local environment is a means of mimicking the server where the software will actually be running from. Just attempting to prove that it will work before deploying and potentially breaking something

Comment: What I'm trying to say is if you just put the repos in the data directory, GitLab won't magically pick them up as repos. Since you installed the omnibus package, you already have well defined permissions. If the built-in import function "Repo by URL" is really no option then create a new project and go the clone/push route.

Comment: Thank you, I went for the `git clone --mirror` option before changing the upstream of my local repo and it seems to work for me now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import projects to GitLab with git you have two options:

1. Use the built-in import capabilities, namely the import "Repo by URL". This way GitLab will do the import process for you which means creating a Project and pulling the files from a remote repository.
2. Create a Project and `pull`/`clone` the files yourself.

There currently is no way to just put the repositories in the folder where GitLab puts them. As GitLab has to create database entries and such only the two options above will work.

Comment: Thanks @Fairy, as mentioned in my comment above, I found `git clone --mirror` helpful for your second point. Posting here for visibility